# How to get dictionary of files stored in file input in javascript?

Tags: javascript, file, dictionary, base64

Now I have this code that converts list of files selected in `<input type="file" multiple/>` to list of base64's.

```
text = $('#input-' + id).val();
var files = document.querySelector('#files' + id + ' > input[type=file]').files;
if (text != '' || files.length > 0) {
    var files_obj = [];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(readerEvt) {
        var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
        files_obj.push(btoa(binaryString));
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        reader.readAsBinaryString(files[i]);
    }
    while (files_obj.length < files.length) {}
    $('input[type="file"]').val("");
    files_json = JSON.stringify(files_obj);
    json = '{"action": "message", "from": ' + userId + ', "text": "' + text + '", "room": ' + id + ', "files": ' + files_json + '}';
    socket.send(json);
```

Now I want to convert these files to dictionary:

```
files_obj = {"file1.txt": "fIle1bAse64==", "file2.png": "FilE2BaSE64=="}
```

How to implement it?

Comment: Please show the example of the dictionary you want.Which is the key?Which is the value?

Comment: pls, look to example at next to last line in answer. I want dictionary with names of file as keys and theirs base64 as values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want is:

```
var input = document.getElementById(id);
var files = input.files;
var obFiles = {};
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e){
            obFiles[theFile.name] = e.target.result;
        }
    })(f);
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
}
```

I think it will work